# Standard fallback languages for translation

Tags: translation, gettext, culture

I have an app that's translated into ~10 languages. Of course we try to keep the translations up-to-date but it's never perfect, many are community-contributions, and we often release updates with translations that are only at various levels of (in)completeness (say 80%).

So missing translations are a fact of life. By default `gettext` falls back to the source language (English) when a translation is not available.

I have translations for pt_PT, pt_BR, and es_ES among others. In that case I think it would be preferable to fall back

- from pt_PT to pt_BR to es_ES and only then english;
- from pt_BR to pt_PT to es_ES and only then english;
- from es_ES to pt_BR to pt_PT and only then english;
- from any other language to english.

My questions are

- Is this culturally appropriate?
- Is this in any way "worse" than simply falling back to english (as now)?
- Is there any standard list of fallback locales like this? "worst-case but better than english"

I saw [gettext: How to fall back to the base language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724198/gettext-how-to-fall-back-to-the-base-language) talks about fallback Czech->Slovak->English and [Gettext fallbacks don't work with untranslated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367405/gettext-fallbacks-dont-work-with-untranslated-strings) talks about fallback Spanish->English->Russian.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer depends on how exactly you are retrieving translations.

If you are using a GNU gettext compatible framework, setting the environment variable `LANGUAGE`, maybe in combination with `LANG`.  Try this:

```
export LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt_PT:pt:es_ES:es:en
export LANG=pt_BR
```

You can find more details in the file `ABOUT-NLS` which gets installed with internationalized packages, or online for example at http://www.sensi.org/~alec/locale/other/about-nls.html.